# Syntax Analysis with MS Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a litle but stupid problem. I started working with MS Roslyn, and I am trying to do the Walkthrough, but directly at the beginning an error occurred...

> error CS0117:  'Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp.SyntaxTree' does not contain a
>   definition for 'ParseCompilationUnit'

I do not understand why it occurred... maybe one of you had the same problem.

My Sourceode:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
using Roslyn.Services;
using Roslyn.Services.CSharp;

namespace gettingstarted2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseCompilationUnit(
                @"using System;
                using System.Collections;
                using System.Linq;
                using System.Text;

                namespace HelloWorld
                {
                    class Program
                    {
                        static void Main(string[] args)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
                        }
                    }
                }");

            var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it's an issue with the walkthrough. Use `ParseText` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the date mentioned in the walkthrough you were following?  The method was renamed from `ParseCompilationUnit` to `ParseText` for the September CTP. If you a previous CTP installed, it's possible that the walkthrough wasn't updated properly when you installed the latest CTP.

I would recommend uninstalling and reinstalling the CTP or using repair.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! That was the information I was looking for! Interesting, that i did not found anything about the renameing... Even for this purpose I used the online version from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx to be shure, that is the newest one... but no it is not, it is from june 2012, in the installation directory is a guide dated to September 2012, with the ParseText instead of ParseCompilationUnit.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I will work on getting the online ones updated!

Answer (score 0):

@Anton to be shure, that is the newest one... You can use Nuget to install Roslyn.

Run the following command in the Package Manager Console :  PM> Install-Package Roslyn