# Locating a Nuget package from its fully qualified name

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm trying to compile the C# code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182922/syntax-analysis-with-ms-roslyn):

```cs
using System;
// < ... omitted ... >
using Roslyn.Compilers;
using Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp;
using Roslyn.Services;
using Roslyn.Services.CSharp;
```

- Usually, when I use `pip` or `npm` the package name is easily found from the [FQN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name)
- With `nuget` I can't find the corresponding package (neither with google search nor with [Nuget search](https://www.nuget.org/))

```bash
$ nuget install Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp # <--- use raw fqn, doesn't work         
# ... omitted ...
Unable to find package 'Roslyn.Compilers.CSharp'

$ nuget install Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset  # <--- 1st result Nuget search
$ nuget install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilers # <--- 2nd result Nuget search
$ nuget install Microsoft.CodeAnalysis           # <--- 3rd result Nuget search
```

I (semi) blindly tried some other packages but none worked:

```
main.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Roslyn' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

How can I systematically infer the Nuget relevant package from the fqn?

Comment: do you have some nuget.config-file in your users directory? Typically nuget uses this file and uses the feeds listed there.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain no, this is literally the first code I have ever written in C#. But if this is similar to `package.json` / `Pipfile` / `requirements.txt` then someone would have to write the package name there, no?

Comment: probably, I think nuget will by default only watch for `nuget.org`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nuget package you are looking for is `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`. Add it to your project with:

`dotnet add package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`

Also, some things have changed, the code from the post you linked works with .NET 6 if changed like this:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace gettingstarted2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(
                @"using System;
                using System.Collections;
                using System.Linq;
                using System.Text;

                namespace HelloWorld
                {
                    class Program
                    {
                        static void Main(string[] args)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(""Hello, World!"");
                        }
                    }
                }");

            var root = (CSharpSyntaxNode)tree.GetRoot();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works thanks ! so just more guess-and-check next time, right?

Comment: It was an old code snippet, some things have changed, other have been renamed etc. If you can get the old SDK it was created for, it probably still works. Glad it works now :)